# Prometheus: what is default time interval for a Summary percentile?

Tags: prometheus

Suppose I use a Summary metric named my_summary, and I want to see this metric in promcol. 
Let's say I write:

```
my_summary{percentile="0.99"}
```

I expect to get the average value of values "stored" in the 99-th percentile. It means that we take all values that have been observed in certain time interval (for example last 1 or 2 or 5 minutes, as well as 1 or 5 or 10 seconds), sort them from lowest to highest and take the top 1%. The question is: **"what is this time interval?"**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duration of the window is a dependent on the client library implementation and can be configurable.

For instance, both the Java and the Go implementation allow setting the duration of the window and both default to a window of 10 minutes.

See relevant the Go library source code [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus#pkg-constants) and the relevant Java library source code [here](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/blob/master/simpleclient/src/main/java/io/prometheus/client/Summary.java#L70-L80).